# HQL to write condition for @OneToOne and @JoinColumn column

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hql

I use Hibernate and Spring 4 in my application.
I created next database entities structure:

```
public static class Entity1 {
    @Id
    private String guid;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "name", referencedColumnName = "guid")
    private Localized name;
    private String another_data;


}

public static class Localized {
    @Id
    private String guid;
    private int locale;
    private String data;

}
```

Table ***Localized*** contains data like:

```
+-----------------+--------+---------------------------------------+
|      guid       | locale |                 data                  |
+-----------------+--------+---------------------------------------+
| random_string_1 |      1 | localized string (in English)         |
| random_string_1 |      2 | localized string (in German)          |
| random_string_2 |      1 | another localized string (in English) |
| random_string_2 |      2 | another localized string (in German)  |
+-----------------+--------+---------------------------------------+
```

In my database (MySQL) table ***Localized*** has combined primary key (guid+locale).

In my application I want to get ***Entity1*** object using locale that I provide.

I can describe it in SQL:

```
SELECT e.guid, l.data, e.another_data 
    FROM Entity1 AS e, Localized AS l 
    WHERE l.locale = :myLocale AND l.guid = e.name;
```

But when I try query like this in Spring 4 repository, I got error that object can't convert to Entity1 (I understand why).

I tried another HQL, like this:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Entity1 AS e WHERE e.name.locale = :locale")
Page<Entity1> findAllByLocale(Pageable pageable, @Param(Entity1.FIELD_LOCALE) int locale);
```

and it gives me correct result except name, because it is still in incorrect language (with id 1). I also tried to use JOINs but it does not help.

Could anyone please give me advice how I can done my task? Thanks a lot.